# Sonarqube not taking required quality profile

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have two types of codes(Webmethods and Axway) which need to be scanned using sonarqube. For webmethods SCA, I have installed a i8c flow [plugin](https://github.com/I8C/sonar-flow-plugin) in sonarqube server and for axway I have installed [json](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-json-plugin) plugin.
After running the analysis using sonar-scanner, sonarqube is able to scan **.json** files but it is not scanning **.xml** files. On debugging I found is that sonarqube is taking 2 quality profiles, **Sonarway json** and **i8c flow rules**, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx5E0.png). I am not able to understand how sonarqube is taking these 2 quality profiles. I am expecting **Sonarway json** and **Sonarway xml** quality profiles over there so that it scan both .json and .xml files.

```
1. Github code I am scanning, `https://github.com/amolmandloi037/axway-swagger-maven`
2. Command in jenkins for scanning, 
            stage('sonar analysis') {
            def scannerHome = tool 'sonar'
            withSonarQubeEnv() {
            bat(/${scannerHome}\bin\sonar-scanner.bat -Dsonar.projectKey=test2 -Dsonar.projectName=test2 Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=akmandloi/)}}
```

I tried adding json quality profile for a project in sonarqube server as well but still showing only 2 quality profiles in project information. Is there any way to remove the quality profile from project or any command to specify which quality profile to use.

Comment: Someone with admin rights over the project needs to go to Administration and Quality Profiles, and set the profiles you want to use.  The NEXT scan after that will use the new profiles.

Comment: Hi @DavidM.Karr, thanks for your response, I tried adding that too, but unfortunately I am not able to delete the i8c flow quality profile, this it is not taking the newly added quality profile. I already mentioned this in my question in the last paragraph.